# Using one set of stored procedures for hundreds of identical databases

Tags: database, t-sql, procedure

I inherited a project where each 'customer' has its own database. There are hundreds of databases. Stored procedures are currently not being used.

What are the best practices for consuming data here? Do I keep my stored procedures in the "master" database and use dynamic SQL to muck with data? It seems like there should be a much better way. I don't want to have a job running to push stored procedures around hundreds of DBs to keep all the stored procedures in sync.

This dynamic SQL is working, but I want a better way.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Users_SELECT] 
@DataBase nvarchar(20),
@UserID uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = ''
SET @sql += 'SELECT * FROM ' + @DataBase + '.dbo.Users u '
SET @sql += 'WHERE u.UserID=@UserID '
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@UserID uniqueidentifier', @UserID
END
```

I tried `EXEC sp_executesql 'USE ' + @DataBase + '; GO'` then running a SELECT but I couldn't get that working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This will probably make SQL experts extremely mad, but I'm happy with the solution.

I created my stored procedures in 'master'. I know this is usually a no-no. I then used

```
USE master
EXEC sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject [sp_Users_SELECT]
GO
```

to mark each sproc as a system object. This way they can be called while under a different context. I can then do this:

```
USE DataBase200
EXEC sp_Users_SELECT
```

and it will run in the context of the DataBase200 db, without having to actually deploy the sproc to that database. It is working great so far. Remember that you have to prefix your stored procedures names with `sp_` in order for them to be recognized as system objects.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see whats wrong with deploying the stored procedures to each and every database.

You have to deploy changes to the schema as well, so you hopefully have infrastructure in place to do it automatically. If not it is time build that infrastructure.

Comment: I do not own the databases, nor do I own the ability to create new ones. This is handled by an offline application -- I am supplementing this with a mobile website. I want to refrain from making individual database changes. For now I am writing a quick and dirty data layer and being as careful as I can be to prevent SQL injection attacks.